# How to set multiple flags xml android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I was wondering how and if I could set multiple flags for an android layout.

For example I want to use an autocompletetextview with the text view flags of TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE

and

TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `|`

So in your case you want

```
android:inputType = "textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
```

Example for an EditText

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType = "textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete">
```

For a complete list of flags you can specify in `inputType`, refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).